# Dynamically changing ngClass on increment/decrement of values

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a situation where I would like to add class (using ngClass) to my view based on the change in the value of the output. 
The value of output depends on the response from API, and I'm calling the endpoint every one second to get the data. (Simple Forex Application)

I tried two-way data binding using ngModel and events., but noticed the screen flickering.

Any advice or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

**Adding some code snippet**

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData">
    ..........
    <td>{{ data.price }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to add this class to this data.price value., say the initial value is 100, on next response if it's 101., I would like to add green background and if the value is 99, I would like to add a red background. 
Since the data is changing every one second, I'm having difficulty maintaining the state and adding classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any sample code I'm going to use `div` as the selector. So here it is `<div [class.className]="logicWhenTrue" [class.className]="logicWhenFalse">Content </div>` 
`.className` Will be added to the element if the logic returns `true` otherwise it will ignore the class as if it wast a commented out code. That's why you would need to write one per how ever many logic you have.

***UPDATE***

Try this:

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<tbody>
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of tableData">
  <tr [class.green]="data.price > 100" [class.red]="data.price < 100">
    ..........
    <td>{{ data.price }}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
</tbody>
```

That should add the classes accordingly.

Comment: I have shared some snippet for your ref., the real problem is how to maintain the state and then add the class based on value.

Comment: I see the implementation., It works when we manually set the value., But the data in my application is dynamic, look at my application here, you will get a better picture. http://www.eastminds.com/#/projects/forex

Comment: I have changed the structure check is that sloves the problem. If this doesn't work I have no other solutions for it. Mainly because I haven't face this kind of scenario before. My other solution is to re-generate the component everytime it changes. But that's not best practice.